# Not able upload image in PHP

Tags: php

I have 2 upload fields in form for uploading songs. 1) Upload song and 2) Upload image. In which songs are uploaded easily while image is not uploaded in folder. And it even stores its path in a database, but not only uploads to the particular folder of the image.

Given below is a code of both files.

**UPLOAD-QUERY.PHP**

```
<?php

include 'conf.php';          
$title = $_POST['title'];
$artist = $_POST['artist'];
$category = $_POST['category'];
$language = $_POST['language'];

$uploadDir = 'http://localhost/PHP%20Learning/Music%20Player/'.'songs/'; 
$fileName = $_FILES['path']['name'];
$filePath = $uploadDir . $fileName;
$uploadiDir = 'http://localhost/PHP%20Learning/Music%20Player/'.'images';
$fileiName = $_FILES['ipath']['name'];
$fileiPath = $uploadiDir . $fileiName;


if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["path"]["tmp_name"],"songs/".$_FILES["path"]["name"]) ||
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["ipath"]["tmp_name"],"songs/".$_FILES["ipath"]["name"])) {

mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO `audio` (`title`, `artist`, `category`, `language`,`path`, `ipath`) VALUES ('".$title."', '".$artist."', '".$category."', '".$language."', '".$filePath."', '".$fileiPath."')") or die(mysqli_error($con));
}
```

**UPLOAD.PHP**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <label><b>Select Audio to upload:</b></label></br></br>
    <input type="file" name="path" style="border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <label><b>Select Image to upload:</b></label></br></br>
    <input name="ipath" type="file" style="border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;">
    </br></br>
  </div>
</div>
<-----UPLOAD.PHP
```

Comment: Have you check if error reporting is enabled? Are your logs showing anything? Are any errors being displayed? What specifically is not working?

Comment: Step 1: Learn the difference between a URL, and a file system path.

Answer (score -2):

One most important thing **please do not use these kind of static URL**. Instead Use the Base URL dynamically and append the later part to that. 

For this to work (if it is testing or debugging purpose) you have not use "/" at the end of the line:

Instead of this I am using core PHP's Base URL:

```
define( 'ABSPATH', dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/' );

$uploadiDir = ABSPATH.'Learning/Music/Player/'.'images/';
```

Comment: Sorry, but you're wrong. As 04FS stated, OP doesn't know the difference between an URL and a fs-path.